# Jackson deserialization issue with final classes in Map

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I am using jackson in java to deserialize a json blob which is composed of a map of objects. But unfortunately my code is throwing an exception.

I have the following data blow which I want to deserialize using Jackson:

```
"config": {
    "configItem1": {
        "0": {
            "valueBit": false,
            "valueInt": 0,
            "valueFloat": 0,
            "timestamp": "2016-10-05T13:44:04.223Z"
        },
        "1": {
            "valueBit": false,
            "valueInt": 0,
            "valueFloat": 0,
            "timestamp": "2016-10-05T13:44:04.223Z"
        }
    },
    "configItem2": {
        "0": {
            "valueBit": false,
            "valueInt": 0,
            "valueFloat": 0,
            "timestamp": "2018-03-15T11:39:47.550Z"
        }
    }
}
```

And I have the following model class which I am trying to serialize into:

```
public class VehicleConfigValues {

    private final Boolean valueBit;
    private final Integer valueInt;
    private final Double valueFloat;
    private final DateTime valueDate;
    private final DateTime timestamp;
    private final String changedBy;

    public ConfigValues(Boolean valueBit, Integer valueInt, Double valueFloat, DateTime valueDate, DateTime timestamp, String changedBy) {
        this.valueBit = valueBit;
        this.valueInt = valueInt;
        this.valueFloat = valueFloat;
        this.valueDate = valueDate;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.changedBy = changedBy;
    }

    final static ConfigValues defaultConfig = new ConfigValues(false, 0, 0.0, null, null, null);

    public Boolean getValueBit() {
        return valueBit;
    }

    public Integer getValueInt() {
        return valueInt;
    }

    public Double getValueFloat() {
        return valueFloat;
    }

    public DateTime getValueDate() {
        return valueDate;
    }

    public DateTime getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public String getChangedBy() {
        return changedBy;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Config {

    private Map<String, Map<Integer, ConfigValues>> config;

    public Config() {

    }

    public Config(Map<String, Map<Integer, ConfigValues>> config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public Map<String, Map<Integer, ConfigValues>> getConfig() {
        return config;
    }
}
```

And I have the following main method calling the deserialization of the above blob into these classes:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {

            // Convert JSON string from file to Object
            Config user = mapper.readValue(new File("C:\\mConfig\\config.json"), Config.class);
            System.out.println(user);

        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But unfortunately I'm getting the following error:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class ConfigValues]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: C:\Config\config.json; line: 5, column: 17] (through reference chain: Config["config"])
```

Is anybody able to shed some light on this? I'm finding it difficult to debug why this deserialization is failing

Comment: Error itself is because class does not specify no-arguments ("default") constructor OR construct/static factory method annotated with `@JsonCreator`. Accepted answer shows how to do latter, but you could alternative add a `private` zero-arguments constructor for Jackson to use: that would also work, and then set-methods (or fields directly) would be used to assign values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redefine your beans as given below

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonCreator;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ext.JodaSerializers.DateTimeSerializer;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public class ConfigValues {

    private final Boolean valueBit;
    private final Integer valueInt;
    private final Double valueFloat;
    private final DateTime valueDate;
    private final DateTime timestamp;
    private final String changedBy;

    @JsonCreator
    public ConfigValues(
        @JsonProperty("valueBit") Boolean valueBit,
        @JsonProperty("valueInt") Integer valueInt,
        @JsonProperty("valueFloat") Double valueFloat,
        @JsonSerialize(using = DateTimeSerializer.class) @JsonProperty("valueDate") DateTime valueDate,
        @JsonSerialize(using = DateTimeSerializer.class) @JsonProperty("timestamp") DateTime timestamp,
        @JsonProperty("changedBy") String changedBy) {

    this.valueBit = valueBit;
    this.valueInt = valueInt;
    this.valueFloat = valueFloat;
    this.valueDate = valueDate;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.changedBy = changedBy;
    }

    final static ConfigValues defaultConfig = new ConfigValues(false, 0, 0.0, null, null, null);

    public Boolean getValueBit() {
    return valueBit;
    }

    public Integer getValueInt() {
    return valueInt;
    }

    public Double getValueFloat() {
    return valueFloat;
    }

    public DateTime getValueDate() {
    return valueDate;
    }

    public DateTime getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
    }

    public String getChangedBy() {
    return changedBy;
    }
}
```

and

```
import java.util.Map;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonCreator;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;

public class Config {

    private final Map<String, Map<Integer, ConfigValues>> config;


    @JsonCreator
    public Config(@JsonProperty("config") Map<String, Map<Integer, ConfigValues>> config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public Map<String, Map<Integer, ConfigValues>> getConfig() {
        return config;
    }
}
```

**Few Points:**

- `@JsonCreator` is necessary in case you want to serialize a final class. It should be used on constructor and @JsonProperty annotation is mandatory on parameters in this case.
- By Default Jackson serializes only primitive / POJO classes. If you want to searialize any custom classes (like DateTime), you need to use custom JsonSerializers / Deserializers. For joda DateTime, there was already a serializers in codehaus library.
- Move to Jackson 2 if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately, even with these changes I'm still getting an "unrecognized field error" on "configitem1". Is it not identifying these fields as being items in the map?

Comment: Above is a working code, I wrote in eclipse and run it with codehaus lib version 1.8.5. Which version of jackson library you are using

Comment: Hi, I am running with library jackson-all-1.9.0. Should I move to Jackson 2?

Comment: I am using this library https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.0. Code is working fine, even with this version jar.

Comment: Still throwing an error when I run in IntelliJ, did you make any changes to the JSON blob or main method of the application?

Comment: Just added your json in enclosing curly braces, as it was invalid json. Also edited the json in question . Main method is same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170158/discussion-between-hemant-patel-and-user1501171).

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
Map<String, Config> map = mapper.readValue(jsonInput, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Config>>() {});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. But even with this code I am still getting an error:

org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "configItem1" (Class Config), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: ; line: 3, column: 28] (through reference chain: Config["configItem1"])